# Почему при чтении нескольких строк разом счетчик работает неправильно?

Tags: java

Сначала я задаю сколько ожидается строк, затем считываю их в цикле. Если вводить каждую строчку отдельно, то счетчик работает корректно, но в том случае, если вставить сразу весь набор строчек, то данные считываются до предпоследней строчки, потом необходимо снова нажать `enter` и только после этого программа завершает работу. Почему так происходит и как решить данную проблему?

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int numb = Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++) {
       String [] data = sc.nextLine().split(" ");    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что нет перевода строки в конце посдней строки